# How to return a generic type in Java AST

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree

I am writing a program to modify Java abstract syntax tree (AST), but I don't know how to generate a generic return type. Who can help me?

The generated method looks like this:

```
public static List<String> converter() {
     return new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

I'm using com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeMaker.MethodDef() to generate a method's JCTree, like this:

```
return treeMaker.MethodDef(
                modifiers,
                method,
                returnType,
                List.nil(),
                List.nil(),
                List.nil(),
                methodBody,
                null
        );
```

All is well, but the problem is the 'returnType' parameter

It is a JCExpression type, which I can only set to 'java.util.List'.

How do I set it to `List<String>`?

No one seemed to answer me. What should I do?

Comment: So far, what does your abstract syntax tree look like if you exclude those generic types ?

Comment: @Patrick Thank you for answering, I don't quite understand what you mean. I have revised the problem. Please have a look.

Comment: Ah ! Now I actually understand the question with the added context. Good edit !

Comment: @Patrick Well, Anyway, Thanks for answering :)

Answer (score 1):

**wrap `returnType` with `TreeMaker.TypeApply(JCExpression, List<JCExpression>)`.**

---

for example:

```java
JCTree.JCMethodDecl method = treeMaker.MethodDef(
        treeMaker.Modifiers(Flags.PUBLIC | Flags.STATIC),
        names.fromString("getStrings"),
        treeMaker.TypeApply(
                treeMaker.QualIdent((Symbol) elements.getTypeElement("java.util.List")),
                List.of(treeMaker.QualIdent((Symbol) elements.getTypeElement("java.lang.String")))
        ),
        List.nil(),
        List.nil(),
        List.nil(),
        treeMaker.Block(
            0,
            List.of(treeMaker.Return(
                treeMaker.NewClass(
                    null,
                    List.nil(),
                    treeMaker.TypeApply(
                        treeMaker.QualIdent((Symbol) elements.getTypeElement("java.util.List")),
                        List.of(treeMaker.QualIdent((Symbol) elements.getTypeElement("java.lang.String")))
                    ),
                    List.nil(),
                    null
                )
            ))
        ),
        null
    );
```

will generate something like this:

```java
public static java.util.List<java.lang.String> getStrings() {
    return new java.util.List<java.lang.String>();
}
```